# Malloc function shows error

Tags: malloc

```
`struct node * createLL(struct node *head)
{   
int num;
struct node *new_node;
printf("enter the numbers you want to insert:\n");
printf("enter -1 to quit");
scanf("%d",&num);
while(num!=-1)
{
new_node=(struct node *) malloc (sizeof(struct node *));
new_node->data=num;
if(head==NULL)
{
new_node->next=NULL;
head=new_node;
}
else
{
new_node->next=head;
head=new_node;
}
printf("enter the numbers you want to insert:\n");
printf("enter -1 to quit");
scanf("%d",&num);
}
return head;
}`
```

the malloc used to create a new_node for the linked list of type struct node* is showing error. it says "malloc is not declared within scope"..
i referred books too..the code is same.. couldnot figure out how the error
can be corrected.

Comment: `malloc` should be declared in stdlib.h - are you sure you did `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you included the correct library in the header? Make sure you included

```
#include  <stdlib.h>
```